# How do i pass a variable from view to controller using vue, inertia in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I want to pass the 'CourseId' variable from a page view to a controller in order to delete it, but not sure why I can't access the variable:

view:

```
this.$inertia.get(this.route('applications.courseDelete', CourseId ))
```

route:

```
Route::get('applications/courseDelete', [ApplicationsController::class, 'courseDelete'])->name('applications.courseDelete')->middleware('auth');
```

controller:

```
public function courseDelete($courseId)
{        
   dd($courseId);
}
```

this returns the error, 'too few arguments...'. ive tried adding the model here also, but returns a blank array. sure i'm missing something very obvious here?

Comment: you need to procive id in your route `Route::post('applications/courseDelete/{courseId}', [ApplicationsController::class, 'courseDelete'])->name('applications.courseDelete')->middleware('auth');` also change it to `post` or `delete` not `get` in order to send variable

Comment: thanks @mafortis, also, using the same method, can i pass multiple variables? (this.route('applications.courseDelete', CourseId, UserId ?

Comment: yes you can pass as much variable as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide the method in which you call the get request, I'm guessing you just need to do something like this because you are calling the CourseId from data().

```
this.$inertia.get(this.route('applications.courseDelete', this.CourseId ))
```

Also you need to pass the variable through your route so also change this

```
Route::get('applications/courseDelete/{CourseId}',
    [ApplicationsController::class, 'courseDelete']
)->name('applications.courseDelete')->middleware('auth');
```

Comment: for anyone that wants to pass multiple parameters: this.$inertia.get(this.route('applications.courseDelete', [CourseId, UserId] )) - Route::delete('applications/courseDelete{courseId}/{userId}... - public function courseDelete($courseId, $userId)